# Extendable Diagram Tool

Tags: diagram, user-defined

I need a Diagram Tool with ability to extend set of diagram types and diagram primitives and save them as templates for future use. User-scripted exports or export formats for my diagrams would be nice, too.

For example, I want to make something like this in my game programming:
http://www.bigbluecup.com/yabb/index.php?topic=38322.0

Now I use great UML-only RationalRose-like editor [StarUML](http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/). It is very comfortable, stable and I like it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of some options:

- Ditaa
- PGF/TikZ (uses LaTeX)
- Graphviz
- Dia

Would any of those help you out? TikZ has been my choice for diagrams since I found it. I don't know if there's anything you can't do. Check out the [TikZ examples page](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/). Sorry if I totally missed what you're looking for and provided silly suggestions!